# System hangs installing 13.10 with AMD R9 290X graphics card

Tags: installation, 13.10, ati

Trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy salamander) on a new desktop pc with an AMD R9 290X graphics card hangs on the 'dots' screen. All the dots light up but nothing happens. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by plugging my monitor into the onboard graphics of my motherboard, installing Ubuntu and then following the manual instructions for the catalyst driver (section 3) here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Note: replace references to raring with saucy.

Once everything was installed I was able to reboot and switch the display over to my R9 290X card.